# ServiceStack Fluent Validation - Message Issue

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I am using ServiceStack Fluent Validation and it works great. I did see an issue.

If my return object name is "xxxxStatusResponse", validation works but I do not see the validation message. If the return object is named as "xxxxStatusResult", I can see the validation message.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks
rudrvij

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is [documented in ServiceStacks Error Handling docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#error-response-types). If you use the `{RequestDtoName}Response` naming convention for the Response DTO ServiceStack will return an instance of that Response DTO, so in order for it to be populated with a structured Error Response it **must have a ResponseStatus property**, e.g:

```
public class MyExampleResponse
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```